# Giving specific name to the port number in IIS

Tags: iis, ip

I have hosted my application on server port 99
so the directory is 10.74.16.153:99 or swcoefisbom01:99

but instead to show the portnumber in the web address i want to shoe like swcoefisbom01/myapp

Comment: It sounds like you are mixing the concepts. The root path of your app is `swcoefisbom01`, and `swcoefisbom01/myapp` is a different path, no matter which port number you use.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be mixing path and port number. For a http request, the default port number is 80 (443 for https), and unless you have specified the port number explicit in your url, any client (browser etc) will be using port 80. So, if you're bound to use port 99, you're bound to also include the port number in your URL.

To make a sub path in iis, you can either make a folder on the file structure under the root of your site, or you can add a virtual directory from IIS manager